# Margin on body border in CSS?

Tags: css, border, margin

While, trying to create a body `border` around the website, I am having troubles creating `margin` between the website and the `border`.

I want to have a margin of `20px` around the `border`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this, can anybody help me?

My final goal is for the `border` to look close to [this](http://www.alicecicolini.com).

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your **code**, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). P.S. body border is not the same as container border.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a wrapping div around the content with proper media queries, something like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9d4jn1q/)

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:20px;
    background:#eee;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px) {
    #wrapper {
      margin: 20px;
    }
}

#content {
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried css `margin` property?

```
body
{
 margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two divs that surround everything in your body, like that :

```
<html>
    <head>
        [...]
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="global">
            <div id="global-inner">
                [Your original code ...]
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you just have to do some css

```
#global {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

#global-inner {
    margin: 7% 7%;
}
```

See the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9usf2hmh/

Hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is just use `padding` on your body, or main container.

Keep in mind that in that particular page design, the padding is on left/right and top, the bottom `padding` is part of the footer element and that's how he achieve the `top-border` on the bottom elements

[Here a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wy4Mf0?p=preview)